# how erase the last character of one widget/text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tk-toolkit, self

i have a calculator where we can a screen for watch the numbers already writes,but i want insert a button for erase one character(last) and cant, only can erase the first character

this is the code

```
 def DEL(self,):
    self.pantalla.configure(state="normal")
    self.operacion = self.operacion[:-1]
    self.pantalla.delete("")
    self.pantalla.configure(state="disabled")
```

pd self.pantalla is the text,
self.operacion is the var where do calculate
thank...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do you mean `tk.Text` or `tk.Entry`?

Comment: If it is `StringVar` then you have to use `.get()`, `.set()`. If it is normal string then you have to remove all from widget and put new text again - for label  it need `widget["text"] = new_text`, for entry it need again `insert(new_text)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use `tk.Entry()` then you may need

```
    entry.delete( len(entry.get())-1 )
```

If you use `tk.Text()` then you may need

```
    text.delete('end-2c', 'end')
```

If you use `tk.StringVar()` then you may need

```
    string_var.set( string_var.get()[:-1] )
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
        
# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    print('Entry:', entry.get())
    entry.delete(len(entry.get())-1)

    print('StringVar:', string_var.get())
    string_var.set( string_var.get()[:-1] )

    print('Text:', text.get('0.0', 'end'))
    text.delete('end-2c', 'end')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

string_var = tk.StringVar(root)
entry_var = tk.Entry(root, textvar=string_var)
entry_var.pack()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='DELETE', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```